# Open Office - How to get two different NOW() values to create a start/stop hours worked table

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Column 1 is START, and column 2 is STOP. I want to start work using =NOW() in column 1 and =NOW() in column 2 when finished, but it updates the first column when I do the latter. How can I get something like this in Open Office so I can calculate a time difference for column 3, total hours/minutes/seconds worked.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice there is a shortcut to get a fixed time value -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>.

To find the difference, enter `=B1-A1` in C1.  Format C1 as `HH:MM:SS`.

The shortcut does not work in Apache OpenOffice 4.1.2.  For alternatives, see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=12575.